# format external hdd with udf not working on mac os x lion

Tags: linux, macos, mac, udf

I formatted my 1tb external drive with the following command:

```
mkudffs --media-type=hd --blocksize=512 /dev/sdb
```

It works on linux but when i plug it in a mac (os x lion 10.7) it tells me

> The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer

how can i fix this?

Comment: tried to format to a different format, then re-format to the desired one? it gets messy sometimes changing FS types.

Comment: "Mac OS X 10.4.5 claims to support Revision 1.50 (see man mount_udf), yet it can only mount disks of the plain build properly and provides no virtualization support at all. It cannot mount UDF disks with VAT, as seen with the Sony Mavica issue.[5] Releases before 10.4.11 mount disks with Sparing Table but does not read its files correctly. Version 10.4.11 fixes this problem.[6][7]" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format#Compatibility I would verify which version UDF the mkudffs you ran creates by default.